# Laravel - Many to Many relationship with Datatables.js and Yajra Package

Tags: laravel, datatables, eloquent, laravel-5, datatables-1.10

I need some help, please.

I have two models, `Country` and `Buy`, with `Many to many relationship` between them. I'm using the [Laravel Datatables](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables) by **Yajra** package to display a table of all the countries and buys.

**Countries**

```
Schema::create('countries', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Buys**

```
Schema::create('buys', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->integer('code_one');
    $table->integer('code_two');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**buy_country**

```
Schema::create('buy_country', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('buy_id');
    $table->integer('country_id');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Models**

```
class Country extends Model
{
    public function buys(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Buy', 'buy_country');
    }
}

class Buy extends Model
{
    public function countries(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Country', 'buy_country');
    }
}
```

---

I want to display the country name on the first row, and the products from buys table on child rows.

[image]

How can I do this, with or without Yajra package?

Comment: Have you read this one in its documentation? [here](https://datatables.yajrabox.com/eloquent/master)

Answer (score 0):

For this case I think you should use yajra datatables to populate child at table rows.

You can use jquery Datatables Child Rows and use ajax to populate the data under it.
Based from here : https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html

HTML code:

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>  <!-- Left the head blank for plus icon -->
            <th>Country Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th></th> <!-- Left the footer blank for plus icon -->
            <th>Country Name</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

jQuery Datatables Part:

```
table = $('#example').DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    "order": [[ 2, "asc" ]],   
    columns: [
        {
            "className":      'details-control',
            "orderable":      false,
            "data":           null,
            "defaultContent": '',
            'render': function (){
                return "<i class='fa fa-plus-circle'></i>";
            }
        },
        { //Hiding column country id for sorting purpose
            "data": "country_id",
            "searchable": false,
            "orderable": true,
            "visible": false,
        },
        { data: 'country_name', name: 'country_name' }
    ],
    ajax: function (data, callback, settings) {
        settings.jqXHR = $.ajax( {
            "dataType": 'json',
            "url": "URL",   // Link to Select All from from country
            "type": "GET",
            "data": data,
            "success": callback,
            "error": function (e) {
                console.log(e.message);
            }

        });
    }

});

function format ( d ) {
    // `d` is the original data object for the row
    // This is when you populate data from buy table
    var childContent = '';

    $.ajax({
        url: "URL",  //URL to select from buy_country using country_id and get data from buy (use join table)
        data: {country_id: d.country_id},
        type:'POST',
        dataType: "json"
        success: function( data ) { 

            childContent += '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">' ;

            $.each(data, function (i, elem) {                    

                childContent += '<tr>';
                childContent += '<td>'+elem.name+'</td>';
                childContent += '<td>'+elem.code1+'</td>';
                childContent += '<td>'+elem.code2+'</td>';
                childContent += '</tr>';


            });

            childContent += '</table>';

        }
    });

    return childContent;

}

$('#example tbody').on('click', 'tr.even, tr.odd', function (e) {

        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row( tr );

        if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            $(this).find('td:first-child i').removeClass("fa fa-minus-circle");
            $(this).find('td:first-child i').addClass("fa fa-plus-circle");  
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
            // Open this row
            $(this).find('td:first-child i').removeClass("fa fa-plus-circle");
            $(this).find('td:first-child i').addClass("fa fa-minus-circle");
            row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();  //When open run formt() function.
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }


});
```